# Blob content-types are erased after updating cache-control

Tags: azure, blob, containers, content-type, cache-control

I have following issue. Recently I have checked Google Pagespeed of my website and decided to set cache-control to all my blobs (images).

After I did that, I noticed, that image responses do not contain any content-types anymore, that are erased.

This is an extract of my code:

```cs
public Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient.CloudBlobContainer container;        
public String cacheControl = "public, max-age=604800";
var options = new Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient.BlobRequestOptions();
options.UseFlatBlobListing = true;

var blobInfos = container.ListBlobs(options);

foreach (var blobInfo in blobInfos)
{        
    var blob = container.GetBlobReference(blobInfo.Uri.ToString());

    if (blob is Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient.CloudBlob)
    {
        blob.Properties.CacheControl = cacheControl;                    
        blob.SetProperties();
    }
}
```

Can you explain why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is expected behavior. When you're setting properties, any property not defined is set to its default value (i.e. empty).

Looking at your code, you're creating a new instance of `CloudBlockBlob` object and by default all of it's properties are set to null (or empty string) and you're only setting the cache-control property.

Instead of creating a new instance of CloudBlob, you should simply cast the `blobInfo` into `CloudBlob` and update it's properties.

I also noticed that you're using an older version of storage client library. I would recommend upgrading to the latest version. Here's some code I wrote which makes use of the latest version and does the same thing.

```
    static void PreserveProperties()
    {
        var account = new CloudStorageAccount(new StorageCredentials(accountName, accountKey), true);
        var blobClient = account.CreateCloudBlobClient();
        var container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("images");
        var blobs = container.ListBlobs(null, true);
        foreach (var blob in blobs)
        {
            var cloudBlob = blob as Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob.CloudBlob;
            if (cloudBlob != null)
            {
                cloudBlob.Properties.CacheControl = "public, max-age=604800";
                cloudBlob.SetProperties();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: "Looking at your code, you're creating a new instance of CloudBlockBlob" Which line?

Comment: This one - `var blob = container.GetBlobReference(blobInfo.Uri.ToString());`. HTH.

Comment: Make sense now! Thanks!